# How to select particular column in Spark(pyspark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

testPassengerId = test.select('PassengerId').map(lambda x: x.PassengerId)

I want to select PassengerId column and make RDD of it. But .select is not working. It says 'RDD' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: [You can access columns pandas-style using DataFrame notation](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/08/12/from-pandas-to-apache-sparks-dataframe.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following,

```
testPassengerID = test.select('PassengerID').rdd
```

this would select the column `PassengerID` and convert it into a `rdd`

Comment: One issue with this is that you get a row back out and so then might have to do what @wabbit suggests.

Answer (score 3):

`'RDD' object has no attribute 'select'`

This means that `test` is in fact an RDD and not a dataframe (which you are assuming it to be). Either you convert it to a dataframe and then apply `select` or do a `map` operation over the RDD.

Please let me know if you need any help around this.

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple columns?

Comment: Yes it is :) You could use `df.select(*list_of_columns_to_select)`

Comment: So you must use a data frame then? Not possible with just a RDD then?

Comment: I think there os no way but my knowledge of RDDs is rustic now :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an RDD each row of which is of the form `(passenger_ID, passenger_name)`, you can do `rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])`. This is for a basic RDD

If you use Spark sqlcontext there are functions to select by column name.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDD happens to be in the form of a dictionary, this is how it can be done using PySpark:

Define the fields you want to keep in here:

```
field_list =[]
```

Create a function to keep specific keys within a dict input

```
def f(x):
    d = {}
    for k in x:
        if k in field_list:
            d[k] = x[k]
    return d
```

And just map after that, with x being an RDD row

`rdd_subset = rdd.map(lambda x: f(x))`